# Prove that $\left|\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z^2+3}\right| < \frac{\pi}{3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Where $\gamma$ is the upper half of the unitary circle $|z|=1$.

First I noticed that $z^2 + 3$ has solutions in $\pm i\sqrt{3}$, then we have that
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2+3}
 &= \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z-i\sqrt{3})(z+i\sqrt{3})} dz \\
 &= \frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+i\sqrt{3}}dz
  - \frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-i\sqrt{3}}dz
\end{split}
$$
And I found that $\left|\pm i\sqrt{3}\right| > 1$, so, those points are not bounded by $\displaystyle \gamma$, therefore, its contour integrals are equal to zero, and
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z^2+3}\right| = |0| = 0 < \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Is my procedure/proof correct?

Comment: Not quite. You started well. But the residue theorem apples to close contours. And $\gamma$ is open. To close it, you need to add the portion on the real axis, between $-1$ and $1$. Computing that integral should be easy.

Comment: You mean that $\gamma = \{|z| = 1, arg(z)\in[0,\pi]\}\cup[-1,1]$?

Comment: I would call that something else, since $\gamma$ is only the first part. Also, the angle is from $0$ to $\pi$ (upper half only)

Comment: Then, should I call it as $\Gamma = \{|z|=1, arg(z)\in[0,\pi]\} \cup [-1,1]$?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. For clarity, I would say first $\Gamma=\gamma\cup[-1,1]$

Comment: With that said, my contour integral should be $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{dz} {z^2+3}$, so, is the proof correct now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109670/discussion-between-andrei-and-societyviper).

Answer (score 2):

The path $\gamma$ is not a loop, and therefore you cannot apply Cauchy's integral formula directly. But if you define $\eta$ as $\gamma$ followed by the path that goes in a straight line from $-1$ up to $1$, then $\eta$ is a loop, and $\int_\eta\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+3}=0$. So,$$\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+3}=-\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+3}.$$And$$0<\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+3}=\left[\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac x{\sqrt3}\right)\right]_{x=-1}^{x=1}=\frac\pi{3\sqrt3}<\frac\pi3.$$